# JMESPath how to write a query with multi-level filter?

Tags: json, html5-video, vimeo, vimeo-api, jmespath

I have been studying official documentation of JMESPath and a few other resources. However I was not successful with the following task:

my data structure is a json from vimeo api (video list):
data array contains lots of objects, each object is the uploaded file that has many attributes and various options.

```json
    "data": [
        {
          "uri": "/videos/00001",
          "name": "Video will be added.mp4",
          "description": null,
          "type": "video",
          "link": "https://vimeo.com/00001",
          "duration": 9,
          "files":[
             {
              "quality": "hd",
              "type": "video/mp4",
              "width": 1440,
              "height": 1440,
              "link": "https://player.vimeo.com/external/4443333.sd.mp4",
              "created_time": "2020-09-01T19:10:01+00:00",
              "fps": 30,
              "size": 10807854,
              "md5": "643d9f18e0a63e0630da4ad85eecc7cb",
              "public_name": "UHD 1440p",
              "size_short": "10.31MB"
            },
            {
              "quality": "sd",
              "type": "video/mp4",
              "width": 540,
              "height": 540,
              "link": "https://player.vimeo.com/external/44444444.sd.mp4",
              "created_time": "2020-09-01T19:10:01+00:00",
              "fps": 30,
              "size": 1345793,
              "md5": "cb568939bb7b276eb468d9474c1f63f6",
              "public_name": "SD 540p",
              "size_short": "1.28MB"
            },
            ... other data
          ]
        },
   ... other uploaded files
]
```

Filter I need to apply is that duration needs to be less than `10` and width of file needs to be `540` and the result needs to contain a link (url) from files

I have managed to get only one of structure-levels working:
`data[].files[?width == '540'].link`

I need to extract this kind of list

```json
[
 {
 "uri": "/videos/111111",
 "link": "https://player.vimeo.com/external/4123112312.sd.mp4"
 },
 {
 "uri": "/videos/22222",
 "link": "https://player.vimeo.com/external/1231231231.sd.mp4"
 },
...other data
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the duration is in your `data` array, you will have to add this filter at that level.

You will also have to use what is described under the section [filtering and selecting nested data](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#filtering-and-selecting-nested-data) because you only care of one specific type of file under the `files` array, so, you can use the same type of query structure `| [0]` in order to pull only the first element of the filtered `files` array.

So on your reduced exemple, the query:

```
data[?duration < `10`].{ uri: uri, link: files[?width == `540`].link | [0] }
```

Would yield the expected:

```json
[
  {
    "uri": "/videos/00001",
    "link": "https://player.vimeo.com/external/44444444.sd.mp4"
  }
]
```

Comment: thank you very much! I used this filter right at https://jsoneditoronline.org and got my data super quick